# Flutter Hive data

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am writing data to a Hive box in flutter using the following data from an API;

```
{
"deliveryAddresses": [
    {
        "deliveryAddressNo": "1130119",
        "deliveryAddressName": "AIRCRAFT MOVEMENTS 2169 (EAA)",
        "pointOfServices": [
            {
                "deliveryAddressNo": "1130119",
                "pointOfServiceNo": "1",
                "pointOfServiceName": "HT54505",
                "pointOfServiceDescription": ""
            },
            {
                "deliveryAddressNo": "1130119",
                "pointOfServiceNo": "2",
                "pointOfServiceName": "WASH BAY",
                "pointOfServiceDescription": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "deliveryAddressNo": "1130147",
        "deliveryAddressName": "TESCO - 6144 - HARROW APOLLO",
        "pointOfServices": [
            {
                "deliveryAddressNo": "1130147",
                "pointOfServiceNo": "1",
                "pointOfServiceName": "ACTE711092",
                "pointOfServiceDescription": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

The data is showing in the Box as i expect however, the 2 pointOfServices for the first account show in the Box as NULL.  The 2nd customers pointOfService gets written OK.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas? Is it because there's 2 sets of data on the first account?

Edited:
Showing my Model code for deliveryAddresses;

```
List<Order> orderListFromJson(String val) => List<Order>.from(json
    .decode(val)['deliveryAddresses']
    .map((val) => Order.orderInfofromJson(val)));

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Order extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String? deliveryAddressNo;
  @HiveField(1)
  String? deliveryAddressName;
  @HiveField(2)
  List<PointOfServices>? pointOfServices;

  Order(
      {this.deliveryAddressNo, this.deliveryAddressName, this.pointOfServices});

  factory Order.orderInfofromJson(Map<String, dynamic> deliveryAddresses) =>
      Order(
          deliveryAddressNo: deliveryAddresses['deliveryAddressNo'],
          deliveryAddressName: deliveryAddresses['deliveryAddressName'],
          pointOfServices: List<PointOfServices>.from(
              deliveryAddresses['pointOfServices']
                  .map((pos) => PointOfServices.fromJson(pos))));
}
```

Points of service model;

```
List<PointOfServices> posListFromJson(String val) =>
    List<PointOfServices>.from(json
        .decode(val)['pointOfServices']
        .map((val) => PointOfServices.fromJson(val)));

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class PointOfServices {
  @HiveField(7)
  String? deliveryAddressNo;
  @HiveField(8)
  String? pointOfServiceNo;
  @HiveField(9)
  String? pointOfServiceName;
  @HiveField(10)
  String? pointOfServiceDescription;

  PointOfServices(
      {this.deliveryAddressNo,
      this.pointOfServiceNo,
      this.pointOfServiceName,
      this.pointOfServiceDescription});

  factory PointOfServices.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> pointOfServices) =>
      PointOfServices(
          deliveryAddressNo: pointOfServices['deliveryAddressNo'],
          pointOfServiceNo: pointOfServices['pointOfServiceNo'],
          pointOfServiceName: pointOfServices['pointOfServiceName'],
          pointOfServiceDescription:
              pointOfServices['pointOfServiceDescription']);
}
```

Code that builds the the data and adds to the box;

```
  if (!Hive.isBoxOpen(orderInfoBox)) {
    _orderInfo = await Hive.openBox<Order>('orderInfo_db');
    _orderInfo.clear();
    var result = await OrderNetwork().get();
    var resultBody = await json.decode(json.encode(result.body));
    List<Order> orderList = List<Order>.empty(growable: true);
    orderList.addAll(orderListFromJson(resultBody));

    _orderInfo.addAll(orderList);
```

Comment: Please share the code for writing data to  HiveDB. Also, did you get any errors ?

Comment: Hi @NirmalCode edited my post to show the relevant code. Thanks!